# return rows which elements are duplicates, not the logical vector

Tags: dataframe

I know the duplicated-function of the package dplyr. The problem is that it only returns a logical vector indicating which elements (rows) are duplicates.
I want to get a vector which gives back those rows with the certain elements.

I want to get back all the observations of A and B because they have for the key Name and year duplicated values.

I already have coded this:

```
 >df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(any(( ?????)))
```

but I dont know how to write the last part of code.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using `dplyr` can be achieved by grouping on both `Name` and `Year` to calculate count. Afterwards group on only `Name` and filter for groups having any `count > 1` (meaning duplicate):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name, Year) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(any(count > 1)) %>%
  select(-count)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups: Name [2]
#   Name   Year Value
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 A      1990     5
# 2 A      1990     3
# 3 A      1991     5
# 4 A      1995     5
# 5 B      2000     0
# 6 B      2000     4
# 7 B      1998     5
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Name    Year    Value
A       1990     5
A       1990     3
A       1991     5
A       1995     5
B       2000     0
B       2000     4
B       1998     5
C       1890     3
C       1790     2",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```